# What is the strange object on 737-800 exterior, on the aft right side?

Tags: boeing-737, feature-identification

I was unable to locate this on a "real life" picture of the aircraft, so have attached an image from my simulator. What is the function/purpose of this object on the exterior of the 738? It seems like it would decrease efficiency so it must surely serve an important role? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: On the [real aircraft](https://i.redd.it/88zpxbe5zblx.jpg), and while we are here, let's [see inside](https://www.flightsim-corner.com/wp-content/uploads/B373-APU.jpg).

Comment: That's the right turn arrow.  I fly for miles with those blinking sometimes...

Comment: @mins the downward angle of that image is a little unsettling...

Comment: Those are the top secret Chemtrail generation port.  BTW its about the size of a womp rat hole...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's the air inlet for the [Auxiliary Power Unit (APU)](http://www.b737.org.uk/apu.htm).

Slide 18 [here](https://www.slideshare.net/theoryce/b737-ng-apu) has an image labelled "APU Air Inlet door with Vortex Generator". The inset image on the slide looks almost exactly like your posted image.

I found a much better image [here](http://www.pbase.com/flying_dutchman/image/82321975), captioned "Boeing 737-800 with APU inlet".

There is some discussion about *why* the 737 has vortex generators for the APU on [this thread on PPRuNe](https://www.pprune.org/tech-log/432756-737-vortex-generators-apu-inlet.html).